# How can I get the negation of $\exists!$ (unique existential quantification)?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

How can I get the negation of $\exists!$ (unique existential quantification)? if it's $\forall$, So if I wanna re-negate the last one, I'll get $\exists$ but it's not the same as what we started with! Did I do something wrong here?

For example: $$P : \exists! x\in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } x^2 = 0$$ it means $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}\text{ such that } x^2 = 0\wedge x $ is unique, So the negation is $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\space x^2 \ne 0 \vee x \text{ isn't unique}$ is this a false statement?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need to do this for?

Comment: See [Uniqueness_quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification) and negate the equivalent expression that uses ordinary existential and universal quantification.

Comment: Maybe I'm just lacking context, but this all seems too fancy for something that should be pretty simple.  It seems like a negation of "there exists unique" is just "there does not exist or there exists more than one".

Comment: You want to be careful to use parentheses to clarify the *scope* of the quantifier and the variables it's quantifying.  So $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}((x^2 \neq 0)\lor ((x^2 = 0)\implies \exists y\in\mathbb{R}(y\neq x \land y^2=0))$

Comment: Actually, I see my statement immediately above is "redundant", i.e., it is enough, for the op's purposes, to write either $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}((x^2 = 0)\implies \exists y\in\mathbb{R}(y\neq x \land y^2=0))$ OR $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}((x^2 \neq 0)\lor \exists y\in\mathbb{R}(y\neq x \land y^2=0))$

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is unpack what $\exists !$ means.

$\exists ! x \phi(x)$ is shorthand for
$$\exists x (\phi(x) \wedge \forall y (\phi(y) \rightarrow y=x))$$

so negating this gives
$$\forall x(\neg \phi(x) \vee \exists y(\phi(y) \wedge y \ne x))$$
which is to say: either no $x$ satisfies $\phi$ or there is a $y$ distinct from $x$ which satisfies $\phi$.

This is of the form $\forall x (\neg A \vee B)$, which is the same as $\forall x(A \to B)$, so we could write
$$\forall x(\phi(x) \to \exists y(\phi(y) \wedge y \ne x))$$
which is to say: if $x$ satisfies $\phi$ then there is a $y$ distinct from $x$ which does too. This is closer to how I'd think intuitively about the negation of $\exists!$.

Unfortunately there isn't a very succinct way of writing it.

Answer (score 6):

The symbol $\exists !$ means "there exists a unique", and is not really a unit, it carries two conditions: existence and uniqueness. The negation of $A$ and $B$ is not $A$ or not $B$, in symbols:

$$\lnot (A \wedge B) = \lnot A \vee \lnot B.$$

The negation of "there exists" is "there does not exist". The uniqueness assumes existence, and its negation is plurality. So it seems to me that the negation is

*There does not exist, or there exist many, such that...*

Answer (score 4):

Just write it out, unfold definitions and keep pushing the negation inwards

$\neg \exists ! x, P(x)$

$\neg \exists x, (P(x) \wedge (\forall y, P(y) \to y=x))$

$\forall x, \neg (P(x) \wedge (\forall y, P(y) \to y=x))$

$\forall x, \neg P(x) \vee \neg (\forall y, P(y) \to y=x)$

$\forall x, \neg P(x) \vee \exists y, \neg (P(y) \to y=x)$

$\forall x, \neg P(x) \vee \exists y, P(y) \wedge y\not = x$

You can read this as saying that for each $x$ we must not have $P(x)$ or there's some $y$ satisfying $P(y)$ which isn't $x$. So that could happen if there's absolutely nothing satisfying $P(x)$, or if there's multiple things satisfying it.

Answer (score 3):

Using the simplest definition of $\exists!$ I know, which is $$\langle \exists! x :: P(x) \rangle \;\equiv\; \langle \exists y :: \langle \forall x :: P(x) \equiv x = y \rangle \rangle \;,$$ the negation you're looking for is $$\langle \forall y :: \langle \exists x :: P(x) \equiv x \not= y \rangle \rangle \;.$$

Comment: Interesting. However the negation is not performed correctly, it should be $\langle \forall y :: \langle \exists x :: P(x) \not\equiv x = y \rangle \rangle$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I think it is correct, since $P \equiv (E \not= F)$ (my version) is equivalent to $P \equiv \lnot(E = F)$, which is equivalent to $P \not\equiv (E = F)$ (your version).

Comment: You are right, although I certainly did not see this immediately. Your point is that for _constant_ Boolean values $A,B$ one has that saying $A\not\equiv B$, which one might as well write $A\neq B$ because they are just values, is the same as saying $A=\lnot B$ (by truth tables or by the excluded middle if you like). I'll give you +1.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\exists! x : E(x)$ if you want to negate that, you have to take $\exists x : E(x) \Rightarrow \exists y\neq x : E(y)$.

Comment: Let's see if it works. First, $\exists ! x : x=0$. Your negation seems to claim that $\exists x : x=0 \implies \exists y \neq x : y = 0.$ So, $x=0$ and $y=0$ yet $x \neq y$?

Comment: @FlybyNight: What you appear to be saying is that the negation of a true statement is false... is there a problem with that? The problem with Stefan's answer is that, as written, the $x$ before the $\Rightarrow$ needn't be the same as the $x$ after the $\Rightarrow$. The whole statement needs to be quantified by $\forall x$ and the first $\exists x$ needs to be removed.