# Proof: $f: A \to B$, if $f$ is bijection then $\forall a\in B \exists ! b\in A (f(b) = a) $

Tags: functions

I musti proof the following:

" let $f: A \to B$, if $f$ is injection then $\forall a\in B \exists ! b\in A (f(b) = a)$"

proof: by contraddiction, therefore the negation of $\forall a\in B \exists ! b\in A (f(b) = a) $ is $\forall a \in B \exists c \in A (f(c) = a$ and $ c \neq b)$, but by hypothesis $f$ is bijection, injection and surjection, so $c \neq b$ then $f(c) \neq f(b)$, but $f(b) = a $ and $f(c) = a $ then $a \neq a$.. a absurd!!

Is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Urgh, why is $a ∈ B$ and $b ∈ A$?

Comment: of course... sorry! A TYPO

Comment: @K.Stm., for all the rest is OK??

Comment: $f$ needs to be surjective for every element of $B$ to have a nonempty preimage. Although I can't say what $\triangleq$ means.

Comment: true... so $f$ needs to be surejective... the simbol $\triangleq$ is like $:=$..

Comment: $\exists!$ means there exists *exactly* one. With injective, I'd have expected something with *at most* one.

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc But $:=$ makes no sense here as $\forall a\in B\exists! b\in A(f(b)$ cannot be a definiendum and $a)$ cannot be a definiens. I suppose you want to simlpy use $=$ instead.

Comment: There's too much notation. Using English doesn't make you less rigorous, you know.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen... yes yes, sorry!!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, but $f$ must to be bijective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Why “$a ∈ B$” and “b ∈ A”? Why? And why “$\triangleq$”?

Secondly, your statement is wrong:
It basically says that every injective function is bijective.
But there are easy counter-examples:

- Set $A = [0..∞)$, $B = ℝ$ and let $f$ be $[0..∞) → ℝ, x ↦ x$.
  Then $f$ is certainly injective but for $a = -1 ∈ B$ there is no $b ∈ A$ such that $f(b) = a$, or much simpler:
- $\{1\} → \{1,2\}, \, 1 ↦ 1$ or even simpler:
- the empty map $∅ → B$ for any nonempty set $B$.

And thirdly, the negation of $∀a ∈ B\, ∃! b ∈ A:\, (f(b) = a)$ is really:
$$∃a ∈ B\, \big(∀b ∈ A:\, f(b) ≠ a \big) ∨ \big( ∃ b_1, b_2 ∈ A:\, (f(b_1) = a ∧ f(b_2) = a ∧ b_1 ≠ b_2)\big)$$
And in English: There is an $a ∈ B$ which is either not hit by $f$ or hit by two different $b_1$, $b_2$ in $A$.

Also, your argument is hard to follow and does not seem very logical.
But my guess is that you mixed up some notions.

Comment: I edited it... but in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228285/how-can-i-get-the-negation-of-exists-unique-existential-quantification the negation of exists unique existential is thinked intuitively..

Comment: Therefore in my hypothesis $f$ must to be bijective?

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc Well, I cannot know what you are supposed to prove, but it would at least make more sense. Do you see why that porperty of functions, viz to have a unique preimage, is in fact equivalent to being bijective? And do you see that your statement – as you formulated it – is indeed false?

Comment: Now I understand!

Comment: Well, … glad to help, I guess?

Comment: of course.....!!